# Professor's bubble sort vs my bubble sort

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, bubble-sort

SO I have 2 bubble sorts: 1 from lecture slides, another I wrote on my own:

```
def lecture_bubble(L):
    while True:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(L) -1):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i+1] ,L[i] = L[i], L[i+1]
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
        # No swaps this pass ; therefore sorted
            return L

def bubble_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        swapped = False
        for j in range(len(array)-1,i,-1):
            if array[j] < array[j-1]:
                array[j], array[j-1] = array[j-1], array[j]
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
            return array
    return array
```

Comparing both of them:

```
Time taken for lecture_bubble is 4.485383749008179

Time taken for bubble_sort is 0.00061798095703125
[Finished in 4.6s]
```

Can someone explain why my bubble_sort is taking significantly lesser time to sort an array?

Also can my bubble sort be further improved?

Comment: We need to see how you actually tested this. My guess: you called your bubble sort on an array you'd already sorted with the professor's sort.

Answer (score 0):

Professors code executes till "if not swapped" is true. Your's will execute till either "the end of the for loop" or "if not swapped". Your code may not work for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Professor's algorithm stops sorting once it iterates through all elements without making any swap — which means the array is sorted. Have written the same algorithm in Javascript below

Comparing each with the neighbor and swapping if first is greater than the next

```
function bubbleSort(arr){

  console.log("Input Array");
  console.log(arr);

  let i = 0
  let temp;
  let notSorted;
  do {
    notSorted = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length-i; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
        notSorted = true;
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = temp;
        console.log(arr[j],"swapped with",arr[j+1])
        console.log(arr);
      } else {
        console.log("SKIP");
      }
      console.log(j, arr.length-i);
    }
    i++;
  } while (notSorted)
  console.log("Sorted using Bubble Sort");
  return arr;
}
// console.log(bubbleSort([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])); // uncomment to run and see how efficient this algorithm is when array is sorted
console.log(bubbleSort([5,8,18,4,19,13,1,3,2,20,17,15,16,9,10,11,14,12,6,7]));
```